# VHDL, confused over syntax "" &

Tags: syntax, concatenation, vhdl

There's some VHDL code I'm going through for finals and came across some confusing syntax. I understand that it is because of type differences but don't really understand what's going on.
**I'll only post the relevant part of the code and the libraries used**

```
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

count : IN std_logic;
SIGNAL qi : unsigned(w downto 0);

qi <= qi + ("" & count);
```

Basically my question is, what's  ' *"" &* ' ,  does the concatenation with *""* do an automatic conversion to the other type?

Thanks in advance

EDIT

Cause of the type conversion confusion here's the rest of the code

```
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.ALL;
USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;

ENTITY counter_alt IS
GENERIC (w : integer := 8);
PORT (clk, load, count : IN std_logic;
        d : IN unsigned(w-1 downto 0);
        q : OUT unsigned(w-1 downto 0);
        co : OUT std_logic);
END counter_alt;


ARCHITECTURE bhv OF counter_alt IS
SIGNAL qi : unsigned(w downto 0);

BEGIN
    PROCESS(clk)
        BEGIN
        IF rising_edge(clk) THEN

        IF load='1' THEN 
        qi <= '0' & d;
        ELSE qi <= qi + ("" & count);
        END IF;
        END IF; 

    END PROCESS;
q <= qi(w-1 downto 0);
co <= qi(w); 
END bhv;
```

Comment: Are you positive these are all relevant libraries, or are there some more like `ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all`?

Comment: the program compiles and runs perfectly with the above library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The empty string `""` is an empty unsigned vectors in that context, since the `USE ieee.numeric_std.ALL;` is included, and the relevant expression involves signals of type unsigned.

So the result of `("" & count)` has type unsigned, thus can be used in addition without any further type conversion.  The concat with `""` serves as an implicit type conversion to unsigned in that case.

Comment: I'm not sure that's pedantically correct... The result of ("" & count) is a std_logic_vector.  I'm not sure the compiler *should* allow you to add that to an unsigned... but I'm away from Modelsim at the moment.

Comment: The expression was tried in ModelSim before I submitted the answer, so you can indeed do `sl <= '0'; slv_00 <= "" & sl; uns_00 <= "" & sl;`.

Comment: Double quotes are used for std_logic_vector, unsigned, and signed types in VHDL. The compiler should allow ("" & count) to be assigned to an unsigned type.

Answer (score 1):

By concatenating an empty string `""` to a `std_logic` value a `std_logic_vector` is returned. This can be useful if a `std_logic` value shall be used in an arithmetic expression. The resulting `std_logic_vector` can then be cast to the desired type, e.g. `signed`(quite useless for a number which is 1 bit wide), `unsigned`, `integer`...
Thus, in your example a type cast should still be required, since VHDL does no automatic type conversion from `std_logic_vector` to `unsigned`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, makes a little more sense now. But for your last statement on concerning type conversion. I actually figured as much but there is no type conversion done at all in the rest of the code. That's the reason I was actually a little confused

Answer (score 0):

"" simply designates a null string literal.  By concatenating it with std_logic, it becomes some array type based on std_logic.  Since the "+" operator for adding with an unsigned only supports an unsigned or natural typed value (pre-vhdl-2008), the string value is resolved to unsigned.

The same sort of type resolution happens when you add with a string literal value:

```
qi <= qi + "0101" ;
```

With VHDL-2008, you can now add an unsigned with a std_ulogic (and as a result also std_logic):

```
qi <= qi + count;
```